# Typescript Design for Tilemap with Layers

Tags: typescript, oop

I working on a game in Typescript.  I have a TileMap class that has a list of TileLayer Classes.  Right now each layer is a two dimensional array of a class that implements the ITile interface.  I would like to have each TileLayer to be a specific type.  Right now the high level application knows what type is in layer and casts the returned tile from a layer to that type.

I tried to use a generic but then the TileMap class can't have a list of all the TileLayers.  Was wondering how one would design this in Typescript.  Thanks for any thoughts.